# Meaning of a slogan for an advert

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I found this old airline advert with a “slogan” using 3 by 3 words:

生於斯
情所依

In context, there is a huge calligraphy of 家， which means home. So the first three characters i would interpret as “i was born here (at home)”, but i cant decipher the last character of the first trio. The second trio, entirely i have no idea of.

What does this mean? It feels very poetic. But i also feel it is a bit uncharacteristic because i usually find slogans like this to be 4 by 4 words, not 3 by 3.

Is this entirely common?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

生 = 出生 =born

於斯 = in here

情 = 感情 = emotion/ feeling

所依 = 所依屬 = that belongs to

生於斯，情所依 = (I was) born here, where (my) feeling belongs to (出生在這裡，我的感情所屬的地方)

The slogan is to remind the viewers of their birthplace which they love, to incite homesickness (煽動鄉愁), and encourage travel (鼓勵旅行)

Answer (score 2):

生於斯 情所依

生長在那裡 感情的歸依(屬)

生長的地方就(總)是感情的牽掛

The slogan is to induce the fond memory of where the traveler was born and grew up to encourage travel to that place.

Note:

斯 can be interpreted as "passed" (過去的) as in "逝者如斯".

依 has many meanings and uses, including "牽攀,不捨" as in "臨別依依; "still",
"依然,依就".

Comment: 不是：“生于斯，情所依”吗？？

Comment: @Pedroski Yes, “生于斯，情所依” is simplified Chinese, “生於斯，情所依” is traditional Chinese. See https://www.wearyourchinesename.com/1000help.html#traditional

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that!